# How to get number of followers with Tweepy (no pagination)?

Tags: tweepy

I'm using this function to get all followers from an id:

```
def getAllFollowers(id):
    followers = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id = id)
    temp = []
    for user in followers.items():
        temp.append(user)

    return temp
```

Is there a way to get the number of followers, or friends, tweets, etc... without pagination?? **Only the number.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User objects have `followers_count`, `friends_count` and `statuses_count` attributes for these. See the example response in the Twitter API docs: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users

> The number of followers this account currently has. Under certain conditions of duress, this field will temporarily indicate “0”. Example:
>
> `"followers_count": 21`

Answer (score 4):

Try my solutions for count followers 
https://gist.github.com/3879338
In this code you need paste your data like consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_key, access_secret.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'followers_count' from the [user](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user) object:

```
handle = 'justinbieber'

user = api.get_user(handle)
num_followers = user.followers_count
num_friends = user.friends_count
```